# Script to move images into year and month folder

Tags: bash

This following code searches for `jpg` files of size larger than 500 KB. Its purpose is to move/cp files, depending on their EXIF data, into folders that correspond to the files' year and month.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -size +500k | while read file; do
    yr=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y' "$file")
    month=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%m' "$file")
    folder="/path/to/backup/folder/$yr"
    subFodler=$folder"/"$month
    [[ -d "$folder" ]] || echo mkdir "$folder"
    [[ -d "$subFodler" ]] || echo mkdir "$subFodler"
    echo mv "$file" "$folder/$month"
done
```

Currently it´s a lot of duplicate lines.

Comment: Trivial code typo note: subFodler is a misspelling of subFolder. Glenn Jackman's solution gets rid of this variable, but just for the record...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this invocation of stat is MacOS specific.

Here's how I would shrink your code

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -size +500k -exec sh -c '
    for file in "$@"; do
        folder="/path/to/backup/folder/$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y/%m' "$file")"
        mkdir -p "$folder"
        echo mv "$file" "$folder"
    done
' sh {} +
```

`mkdir -p` will create all missing folders, and it will also suppress errors if the directory already exists.

find's `-exec cmd {} +` feeds several filenames to the given command.

And this looks odd `sh -c 'stuff' sh file ...` -- the 2nd sh will be assigned to `$0` inside the -c script, and the given files will be $1, $2, etc.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! add a " to line 4, at the mkdir line and we are good to go!